# Cannot read properties of undefined trigger when trying to click upon window load

Tags: javascript

I would like to trigger a timer to run upon my page loading for the first time.

This is what I have tried:

```
let countdown;
...
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-time]");
...
function timer(seconds) {
  // clear any existing timers
  clearInterval(countdown);
  const now = Date.now();
  const then = now + seconds * 1000;
  displayTimeLeft(seconds);
  displayEndTime(then);
...
function startTimer() {
  const seconds = parseInt(this.dataset.time);
  timer(seconds);
}
...
window.addEventListener('load', buttons[0].addEventListener('click', startTimer).trigger('click'))
```

I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trigger')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be doing like so :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', startTimer)
```

I am not sure why you want to trigger the click event on the button, but if you have to, you should do something like that :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   buttons[0].addEventListener('click', startTimer)
   const event = new Event('click')
   buttons[0].dispatchEvent(event)
})
```

The error you have is due to the fact that `addEventListener` doesn't return anything having a method called `trigger` (it doesn't return anything at all).

But again, it should be enough to pass `startTimer` as a callback to the `load` event listener, no need to nest an additional event listener and trigger the click event on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error because `addEventListener` doesn't return anything and also `trigger()` a jQuery function that clicks a button.
Instead you can use `.click()`

`window.addEventListener('load', buttons[0].click())`